# Distribution of sum of $n$ random unit vectors in $d$-dimensional space

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, random-walk, bessel-functions, integer-lattices

I'm interested in the following (equivalent) problems, for $d$ around 100-1000, and $n$ fairly small (perhaps up to logarithmic in $d$?):

1. Given $n$ random unit vectors in $d$-dimensional space, what is the probability that their sum has norm at most $\alpha$?
2. How likely is it that an $n$-step random walk in $d$-dimensional space ends up within distance $\alpha$ of the origin?

I've found [one paper](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/dwalks.pdf) (Equation 12) but the results are huge integrals filled with Bessel functions. Really, I only want the largest terms; for example, when $n=2$, the probability is $O(poly(d)\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}^d)$, and that's good enough (although if the $d$ polynomial varies in $n$, I'd like to know). I tried to bound or approximate the Bessel functions, but didn't get anywhere. A reasonable lower bound would also be fine.

Any ideas and/or references?

Comment: isn't the asymptotics given in ex. 2.4 what you are looking for ?

Comment: That seems like it should help, but (a) I can't figure out how they derive $q_n(\nu;x)$ from those asymptotics; (b) when I use that in (12), the result doesn't match the known result for $n=2$